# When opening an external website in a VS Code extension, how can I avoid the security prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension and trying to create my own Authentication Provider.
I use vscode.openexternal() to open a auth page, but a security prompt shows everytime I open it.
How can I disable this?
[security prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnTUR.png)

I want to open the browser without the security prompt

Comment: You cannot. People are deserved to be warned in those cases and you don't really have a good reason to justify.

Comment: But other VS Code extensions I use can achieve this. Did they use a different method to open the page? Or is there a need to request adding the address to some sort of trusted list?

Comment: Most extensions are open sourced, so you can review their exact code. BTW, VS Code repo has more threads for you to dig, like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95670

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of there being a way for an extension to make a domain trusted without the user's consent. I think that's reasonable for security purposes (for the user's protection). You could make it so when your extension is run for the first time, it creates a notification suggesting to configure trusted domains and say in your user documentation that trusted domains are suggested to be configured in a certain way.

##### Old answer from when I misunderstood the question

There's a button right there in the screenshot you showed: "Configure trusted domains". It'll open up the Trusted Domains pseudo-file. You can open the same psuedo-file by running `Manage Trusted Domains` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) .

The top of that psuedo-file contains instructions on what the file does and how to use it. Quoting from part of those instructions:

> ```json
> // Links matching one or more entries in the list below can be opened without link protection.
> // The following examples show what entries can look like:
> ...
> // - "*": Match all domains using either http or https
> ```

So if you want any domain to be trusted for any protocol, it should just work for you to do that: Put `"*"` in the array.

If you want something more specific than that (instead of trusting all domains), then just follow the rest of the instructions there.

Comment: Thanks for your guidence. I tought this "Trusted Domains"file only applied to a single VS Code instance. will this extension installed on other VS Code instances have the same effect?

Comment: The vscode extension I am developing. I want to open a external page using vscode.openexternal() function. The "Trusted Domains"file seems to me only applied to a single VS Code instance. If others install my extension, should they all edit the trusted domains file to disable the security prompt? If so, that's not I want.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot